# Classification into a High number of Classes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, natural-language, many-categories

Consider a classification task wherein the **training data has around 100,000 sentences with around 1000 labels**. These 100,000 sentences can possibly be grouped hierarchically. The task at hand is **given a random input string, find out the most similar of the 100,000 sentences and assign the corresponding label** to the random input string.

The random input string may be only **semantically related to one or more** of the 100,000 labelled sentences and hence can be assigned one or more of the 1000 labels.

Also in the training data, the number of sentences of belonging to individual classes are highly imbalanced.

I have considered a lot of different ways but am not sure which would be the best way to go about it.
The literature says that in general one should **convert the problem to reduce the number of classes by following hierarchical classification**. But has the drawback that the **error rate cascades** over the levels of hierarchy and results in poor overall performance

Other popular suggestion is **convert the problem to one vs one similarity** problem but this approach presents the **issue of high class imbalance**.

Any ideas about how to tackle this problem ?

Comment: What does "1 lac" mean?

Comment: I'm with whuber regarding the meaning of "1 lac." Despite knowing a bit about text mining, NLP, etc., I've never seen this acronym used anywhere. Next, this suggestion doesn't come from classifying semantic "lacs," but is related and may be helpful. To your point about treating the classes hierarchically, some Bayesians developed an approach for modeling massively categorical information, e.g., zipcodes, which can have as many as 36,000 "classes" or levels. See a paper by Steenburgh and Ainslie, *Massively Categorical Variables: Revealing the Information in Zip Codes*. It's out there ungated.

Comment: By 1 lac i mean 100,000. Edited that.
Also i couldn't find any ungated links to the mentioned paper.

Comment: @DJohnson The usual spelling is ["lakh"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh).  (I couldn't discover this *until* I knew what quantity this word was intended to represent!)

Comment: ad lakh: so OP actually means 1,00,000 sentences... :-) and thanks, DJohnoson for that paper hint, very interesting!

Comment: To offer an alternative, I might suggest using word embeddings and train a ConvNet with final softmax layer for your 1000 labels. That's quite trivial to set up and might work, so I'd imagine it worth a shot; You'd probably still need to figure out how to solve  label imbalance issues, but you could even try modelling that in your cost function as a short-cut.

Comment: @fnl thanks. i will give the convnet a try. Also i am not able to find the link to the paper. could u help me out with the link? :)

Comment: Ah! Right you all are. The Steenburgh and Ainslie paper *used* to be ungated. I'm sorry to see that it's status has changed. I have a pdf of it and would be happy to share that. Anyone have suggestions on how to make that happen within the constraints of this site?

Comment: @DJohnson It can be shared as a google drive link.

Comment: Yeah, this closed access nature of science is ridiculous (considering public money payed for almost all of it in the first place...) Luckily, heroes like [ALEXANDRA ELBAKYAN](http://www.nature.com/news/nature-s-10-1.21157#elbakyan) exist, I guess?

Comment: @fnl  m1cro1ce, good idea! Let me know if this link doesn't work ... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6a-JM5QEpG2X3JEdUx1MXAxVFk/view?usp=sharing